# compile report with stimulsoft on linux (wine)

Tags: linux, wine, stimulsoft

I'm working on a project written in C# using Win Forms, I use StimulSoft as a report generator. There is a need to run this project on Linux, for this I use Wine and everything works fine except reports generation, when I try to create a report I get the following error, please tell me what I can do about it.

```
 `'DateTimeConverter' is unable to convert 'System.DateTime' to 'System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.InstanceDescriptor'.

 = STACK TRACE: ==========================
  at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertToException (System.Object value, System.Type destinationType) [0x00047] in <0c924620d2cd4b85a989ca168d44cf08>:0 
  at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertTo (System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object value, System.Type destinationType) [0x00056] in <0c924620d2cd4b85a989ca168d44cf08>:0 
  at System.ComponentModel.DateTimeConverter.ConvertTo (System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object value, System.Type destinationType) [0x000de] in <0c924620d2cd4b85a989ca168d44cf08>:0 
  at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertTo (System.Object value, System.Type destinationType) [0x00000] in <0c924620d2cd4b85a989ca168d44cf08>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.CodeDom.StiCodeDomSerializator.GetArgumentsWithParent (System.Type type, System.Object value, System.Object parentValue) [0x00006] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.CodeDom.StiCodeDomSerializator.GetObjectCreateExpressionWithParent (System.Type type, System.CodeDom.CodeTypeReference createType, System.Object value, System.Object parentValue) [0x0004b] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.CodeDom.StiCodeDomSerializator.GetObjectCreateExpressionWithParent (System.Type type, System.Object value, System.Object parentValue) [0x0000e] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.CodeDom.StiCodeDomSerializator.GetObjectCreateExpression (System.Type type, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.CodeDom.StiCodeDomSerializator.AddCreate (System.Int32 index, System.String parent, System.Object value, System.String name, System.Type type, System.Boolean isList) [0x00085] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.CodeDom.StiCodeDomSerializator.AddCreate (System.String parent, Stimulsoft.Base.Serializing.StiPropertyInfo prop, System.Boolean isList) [0x00015] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.CodeDom.StiCodeDomSerializator.SerializeProps (Stimulsoft.Base.Serializing.StiPropertyInfoCollection props, System.Boolean isList, System.String parentName, System.String referenceName) [0x001b4] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.CodeDom.StiCodeDomSerializator.Serialize (Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport report, System.String name, Stimulsoft.Report.CodeDom.StiLanguage language, System.Boolean serializeData, System.Boolean saveForInheritedReports, System.Object standaloneReportType) [0x000e3] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.CodeDom.StiCodeDomSerializator.Serialize (Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport report, System.String name, Stimulsoft.Report.CodeDom.StiLanguage language, System.Object standaloneReportType) [0x00000] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.ScriptUpdate (System.Object standaloneReportType, System.Boolean allowUseResources) [0x0001a] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Compile (System.String path, System.IO.Stream stream, Stimulsoft.Base.StiOutputType outputType, System.Boolean autoCreate, System.Object standaloneReportType) [0x00245] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Compile (System.String path, System.IO.Stream stream, Stimulsoft.Base.StiOutputType outputType, System.Boolean autoCreate) [0x00007] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Compile (System.String path, Stimulsoft.Base.StiOutputType outputType, System.Boolean autoCreate) [0x00000] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Compile (System.String path, Stimulsoft.Base.StiOutputType outputType) [0x00000] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Compile (Stimulsoft.Base.StiOutputType outputType) [0x00000] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Compile () [0x00000] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Compile()
  at Stimulsoft.Report.Engine.StiReportV2Builder.RenderSingleReport (Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport masterReport, Stimulsoft.Report.Engine.StiRenderState renderState) [0x00201] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.RenderReport (Stimulsoft.Report.Engine.StiRenderState renderState) [0x0041e] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Render (Stimulsoft.Report.Engine.StiRenderState renderState, Stimulsoft.Base.StiGuiMode guiMode) [0x001b3] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Render (Stimulsoft.Report.Engine.StiRenderState renderState) [0x00000] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Render (System.Boolean showProgress, System.Int32 fromPage, System.Int32 toPage) [0x00009] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 
  at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Render (System.Boolean showProgress) [0x00000] in <1d81646d05044636b8ee21dee71efad1>:0 `
```

I have trouble with the updated framework (now it's 4.6) so I can't get the new version of Stimulsoft (now it's 2014.3)